# change decimals numbers in bar chart in r

Tags: r

I hope you can assist me,

I made a bar chart with data labels, but the data labels have a lot of numbers in the decimal.
Do you have an idea of how I reduce this to two? And also add to the thousand.

Thank you!

```
x<-ggplot(averagedf, aes(x=sentiment,y=average_likes))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.7, fill=c('chartreuse4', 'grey', 'firebrick3'))+
  geom_text(aes(label = average_likes), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
x
```

[image]

Comment: `label = round(average_likes, 2)`?

Comment: working thank you!, Do you have an idea about adding the ',' to thousands?